# Is a Lorentz boost as a limit transformation of a separate time/space dilatation possible?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, reference-frames

Given the covariant coordinate transformation to a rotating coordinate system, where you have a [pure length dilatation](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yaakov_Friedman/publication/260264074_Relativistic_Transformation_for_the_Radius_of_a_Rotating_Disk_*/links/00b495306177d2e4c9000000.pdf) (radius) .

\begin{eqnarray*}
cT & = & ct\\
R & = & \frac{r}{\sqrt{1+\frac{\omega^{2}r^{2}}{c^{2}}}}\\
\varPhi & = & \phi-\omega t\\
Z & = & z
\end{eqnarray*}

Here $\omega$ denotes the angular velocity. Coordinates are given in zylindrical coordinates. Capital coordinates are for the inertial reference frame. 
And the covariant coordinate transformation to an uniform accelerated reference frame , where you have a pure time dilatation. Can you understand the spacetime rotation of a Lorentz transformation as the limit of a combination of the above mentioned transformations, in a similar way in which you can interpret the straight line as a circle with infinite radius.

Comment: I don't understand the whole question, but Lorentz transformations are spacetime rotations, whilst your transformation only transforms spatial coordinates and leaves time untouched. Thus, my answer is - probably not.

Comment: Are you trying to unite special and general relativity? I am not sure if it is possible what you are trying to do, but sounds like an interesting idea to me. Post your answer here in case you figure something out=)

Comment: @MsTais Lorentz transformations are a special case of coordinate transformations from General Relativity with flat background spacetime. Thus, SR and GR are already "united", or, I would say, GR is a generalization of SR (thus the name).

Comment: @v217 "And the covariant coordinate transformation to an uniform accelerated reference frame , where you have a pure time dilatation." How come?